# Mutual TLS connection code - Convert working python code to C#

Tags: c#, python, tls1.2

The client code below works in python and connects to a remote server using a mutual TLS connection where the client has the private and public key and the remote server has the public key.

Does anyone know how to write this code in C#
Either using a keyfile\cer combo or a .pfx file.

```
import ssl
import urllib
from http import client
import requests

key_file_path = "*[Path]*\Keyfile.key"
cert_file_path = "*[Path]*\ird_taxlab_co_nz.crt"

response = requests.get('*[URL OF SERVICE]*', cert=(cert_file_path, key_file_path))
```

Comment: [http://ironpython.net](http://ironpython.net)

Comment: Look at `HttpWebRequest`...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert that example to c# you should be able to do the same with `HttpWebRequest` and `X509Certificate2Collection`.

First of all import the certificate with:

```
string certPath = <pfx path>;
string certPass = <password>;
X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
collection.Import(certPath, certPass, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
```

After that create `HttpWebRequest` and add certificate to it:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(/*your URI*/);
request.AuthenticationLevel = AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequired;    
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)request;
httpWebRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(/*take cert from collection*/);    
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

After this you have response which you can process and gather results.